# Apache Mod for using any database engine

Tags: php, database, apache

My friend using one Apache mod for sql-connections. But I don't know name of this mod (my friend keeps it in secret). I was in Google, but I can't found any info about it.

In this mod you can connect to database like that:

```
$db = new db_mod("mysql");
$db->query(....);
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)? Even if that's not it, that's what you should be using...

And it won't be an 'Apache' mod, it will be a PHP class/extension. Apache is a web server and not really for dealing with things like database connections.